# C separate a string into 4 variables

Tags: c, scanf

I'd want to separate a string into 4 parts. What I need is basically this:

`sscanf(string, "%d %d %d %[^\n]", id1, id2, id3, restOfString);`

The var restOfString is a char*
Problem: restOfString must point to the smallest space of memory possible and still contain all the string indicated by the %[^\n].

I wanted just about what asprintf does. It has an internal malloc() that creates the memory space needed to print the string. I wanted the same technique for sscanf(). How can I accomplish that? How can I know the size of the string sscanf() will read?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I completely agree with RushPL about not bothering to micro-optimize for memory. In the more general case, though, where you might have a large string and comparatively small restOfString, here's an approach that aliases `restOfString` to the main string:

```
// char *string, *restOfString;
// int id1, id2, id3, id4;
int result, numStored;
result = sscanf(string, "%d %d %d %d %n", &id1, &id2, &id3, &id4, &numStored);
if (result == 4)
    restOfString = string + numStored;
else
    restOfString = 0;
```

Basically, use %n to grab the current position while parsing, and then use that as an offset into the original string. Note that %n is a specifier that is *very likely* to cause format-string vulnerabilities if used carelessly. If you're doing complicated parsing, you shouldn't be using `scanf` and friends.

Comment: I didn't know about the '%n' specifier but started thinking about a similiar solution having suggested the below in the edit. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. That will do just fine. With that I can work as I want to. I don't need to copy all the string, I just need parts of it and that will allow me to do just that.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `char* restOfString = malloc(strlen(string));` the few extra bytes will not matter if the whole rest of the string is too big to fit on stack. Getting the exact malloc size would be counter productive.

Alternatively if I may suggest, you can skip allocation altogether (but it depends on your needs). As sscanf returns number of elements and note bytes read, you could find the position of rest of the string manually. Not pretty but should work.

```
// sscanf 
sscanf(string, "%d %d %d");
const char* restOfString = strchr(strchr(strchr(string, ' ') + 1, ' ')+1, ' ')+1; // third ' ' +1 gives rest of string
```

Alternatively, you can get exact allocation using:

```
char* restOfStringAlloced = strdup(restOfString);
```